# Carto time-series widget: how to change bucket labels?

Tags: postgresql, sql, carto, date, time-series

I am using the Carto builder animated time-series widget based on a number column that contains a year as a four digit integer.  In the widget's horizontal axis, the buckets are not labeled with integer values but with decimal values (e.g. 1.8k instead of 1800).  People using the map are confused by this.

How can I configure the time-series to use four digit integers for the labels in the timeline?

[image: ts widget]

Comment: Are you using a histogram widget or a timeseries widget? Could you share a screenshot of the map or widget?

Comment: I am using a time-series widget (image added to original post).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the field you are using is stored as an integer. Try to convert it or cast it as date/timestamp. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  *,
  to_date(time_date_t::varchar, 'yyyy') as date
FROM
  table_name

SELECT 
  *,
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    time_date_t || '-01-01 00:00:00',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
  ) as date
FROM
  table_name
```